# Flagging an answer "hides" all the answers

Tags: support, bug

I flagged a non an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16202646/601179), but now I can't none of the answers, including mine!

There is not much to say or adding print-screens, I see only the question and it's comments.

**Update:**
Well just for the fun I added the print screen... maybe it will be helpful for the devs:

**Update 2:** Very weird, now the flag was accepted and the *not an answer* answer was removed and now I can see the other answers. 
[image]

Comment: Does refreshing the page help? (I can see it just fine)

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin, no it does not, if it would I would have mentioned it.

Comment: I flagged the non-answer on that page, and the answers all remained visible. I use Chrome 26 on Mac OS X 10.7.5; you are using Chrome on Windows?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, **Chrome 26 and windows 7**

Comment: FWIW, the non-answer is now gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, read the update of my bug report.

Comment: Have you seen this happen again at all? Or have there not been any additional posts to flag for you to find out?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, No, it is the first time it occurred and I can't explain why it did. BTW, it's weird that no dev commented on the bug-report, I thought bugs should interest them.

Comment: @foo: The devs are busy devving, and the community helps out triaging bugs. Since you only saw this once, it probably was a interrupted page load, which would be a network error, not something the devs can do much about.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, No, I didn't mean it happen only once for that question. It happen all the times (checked more than 10 times) for that question until the flag was handled. But it was the first time I encountered with this bug.

Comment: @foo: No, it happened *once*. You flagged *one* answer, the page reduced to just the question. But then your browser *caches* that page, and when you reload, it reuses the cached copy. Did you try a force-reload at all? Are you using a proxy somewhere that could have cached an incomplete copy?

Comment: @foo: as far as I understand it, you didn't flag multiple answers and saw the bug occur for each of those flag actions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. _"Did you try a force-reload at all"_ **Yes**. _"Are you using a proxy somewhere that could have cached an incomplete copy?"_  **No proxy**.  and if you notice from the print-screen even the *Post Your Answer* button didn't displayed. Well I think I wrote all I got on the matter.

Comment: The thing is that noone else got the same page you got. It helps not being the only one with a problem, and for the problem to be reproducible, otherwise all the devs can do is guess at what could have been wrong at the time.